# Mysql 5.7 replication (A -> B -> C) not working

Tags: mysql

I Am trying to set up the following Mysql 5.7 replications. All the servers are running on the same version(MySQL 5.7.34). The replication working fine between the `servers A to B` and `servers A to C`. But between the `servers C to D` it's not working. There is no error reported in both master and slave MySQL logs and `slave status` also not throwing any errors, but the slave(`server D`) is not getting any data from the master(`server C`).

Replication setup:

```
Master  -> Slave
Server A -> Server B
Server A -> Server C
Server C -> Server D
```

In Master C:

```
mysql> show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |     2033 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show slave hosts;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| Server_id | Host         | Port | Master_id | Slave_UUID                           |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|       102 | 10.13.123.41 | 3306 |         2 | 80fb4290-d6c0-11eb-9f91-* |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In slave D:

```
mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.13.123.40
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 2033
               Relay_Log_File: bl-prod-v2-relay-bin.000003
                Relay_Log_Pos: 2246
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 2033
              Relay_Log_Space: 2463
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 2
                  Master_UUID: bfd4b293-d3ec-11eb-a834-00505696d4ab
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you add info to your question, so it will be clear about which master your are talking when you say "In Master:" ?    It can be `A` or `C`.   Also add info about the `Master_id` for master `A` and master `C`.

Comment: This is really a question for [DBA.se]

Comment: Did you enable [log_slave_updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates) on server `C` ?

Comment: @Luuk, Updated the question. I've enabled the `log_slave_updates` and restarted the DB in `Master ( server C)` and reset the slave details in `Slave (Server C)`.   In the Master(server C).  ``` mysql> show global variables like 'log_slave%';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| log_slave_updates | ON    |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> ```.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, I have created the question in the  "Database Administrators " Forum. Thanks   - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/294879/mysql-5-7-replication-setup